# Add a caret to an element in CSS

Tags: html, css, caret

## problem

I made a `<textarea>` and used Javascript to put the value into a `<pre>` tag (`contenteditable` was being weird), and I want a way to put a blinking caret in the `<pre>`, like pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>. I couldn't just have used the `<textarea>` because I'm making a JSON formatter (I was bored) and I wanted to add syntax highlighting.

## what i have

```js
document.querySelector("pre.stuff").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("textarea.text").focus();
});
document.querySelector("textarea.text").addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("pre.stuff").innerText = this.value;
});
```

```css
textarea.text {
  position: absolute;
    border: none;
  padding: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
pre.stuff {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 250px;
    border: solid gray 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
    tab-size: var(--tab-size);
    overflow: scroll;
    cursor: text;
}
textarea.text:focus ~ pre.stuff, pre.stuff:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: #0066ff55 0px 0px 0px 4px; /* glowwww */
    border: solid #66a3ff 2px;
}
body {
    margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<textarea class="text"></textarea>
<pre class="stuff" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1"></pre>
<br>
I removed the syntax highlighting part :P
```

Also, the focus has to be on the `<textarea>` or it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## i fixed it

I set the width and height of the `<textarea>` to the `<pre>`'s width and height, and set `color` to `transparent` and `caret-color` to `black`. I also removed the border and all the other things, and apparently it works! It's kind of hacky, but when I set the `font-size` and `font-family` to the same as the `<pre>` tag, it works perfectly.

### it's here

```js
document.querySelector("pre.stuff").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("textarea.text").focus();
});
document.querySelector("textarea.text").addEventListener("input", function() {
    document.querySelector("pre.stuff").innerText = this.value;
});
```

```css
textarea.text {
  position: absolute;
    border: solid transparent 2px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 250px;
  color: transparent;
  caret-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
  font-size: 17px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
  background-color: transparent;
}
pre.stuff {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 250px;
    border: solid gray 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
    tab-size: var(--tab-size);
    overflow: scroll;
    cursor: text;
  font-size: 17px;
}
textarea.text:focus ~ pre.stuff, pre.stuff:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: #0066ff55 0px 0px 0px 4px; /* glowwww */
    border: solid #66a3ff 2px;
}
body {
    margin: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<textarea class="text"></textarea>
<pre class="stuff" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1"></pre>
<br>
I removed the syntax highlighting part :P
```

It's not *perfect*, but it works for me.

Comment: Under the Snippet in you question there is a button Copy snippet to answer. Then you can show your fix in the code too.

Answer (score 3):

For this, you would need an absolutely positioned element acting as a caret as there is no property of `textarea` that I know of which allows you to manipulate the caret. So you would have to create custom events whenever the value of your textarea changes.
Here is how you would do so.

Please note that you can remove the transition of the caret if you find it irritating.
Also please note: for this i am using a library, found at [this link](https://github.com/ichord/Caret.js?utm_source=cdnjs&utm_medium=cdnjs_link&utm_campaign=cdnjs_library)

```js
const txtarea = document.querySelector("textarea.text");
        const invis = $('#faux');


        document.querySelector("pre.stuff").addEventListener("click", function() {
          document.querySelector("textarea.text").focus();
        });
        document.querySelector("textarea.text").addEventListener("input", function() {
            document.querySelector("pre.stuff").innerText = this.value;
        });

        txtarea.addEventListener("keyup", move_caret);
        txtarea.addEventListener("keydown", move_caret);


        function move_caret() {
            let select = document.getSelection();
            let index = txtarea.selectionStart;

            let background = getComputedStyle(txtarea).color;

            const editor = $("textarea.text");
            let pos = editor.caret('position');
            let left = pos.left + 2 + "px";
            let top = pos.top + 2 + "px";
            let height = pos.height + "px";
            var css_data = {
                left,
                top,
                height,
                background
            };
            $("#caret").css(css_data);

        }
```

```css
* {
            position: relative;
        }
        textarea.text {
            min-width: calc(100% - 20px);
            word-wrap: nowrap;
            height: 250px;
            border: solid gray 2px;
            margin: 0px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
            tab-size: var(--tab-size);
            overflow: scroll;
            cursor: text;
            opacity: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            position: absolute;
        }
        pre.stuff {
            max-width: calc(100% - 20px);
            word-wrap: break-word;
            height: 250px;
            border: solid gray 2px;
            margin: 0px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
            tab-size: var(--tab-size);
            overflow: scroll;
            cursor: text;
        }
        textarea.text:focus ~ pre.stuff, pre.stuff:focus {
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: #0066ff55 0px 0px 0px 4px; /* glowwww */
            border: solid #66a3ff 2px;
        }
        body {
            margin: 16px;
        }


        #caret {
            width: 2px; 
            display: inline; 
            position: absolute;

            transition: left 137ms linear, top 137ms linear;
            animation: blink 450ms linear alternate infinite;
        }

        @keyframes blink {
            0% {opacity: 0;}
            20% {opacity: .5;}
            75% {opacity: .78}
            100% {opacity: 1}
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Caret.js/0.3.1/jquery.caret.min.js" integrity="sha512-qclRGh1kwCdmGsi68M9XYAhbCC4xpGRq9VqVlYAQmsG29wQG0DKke/QiMFmuFY1NGXdJ75Wjkhez5nMcuTelgQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="caret"></div>
    <span id="faux" style="display:none"></span>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <textarea class="text"></textarea>
    <div style="display: inline; width: min-content; height: min-content;">
        <pre class="stuff" spellcheck="false" tabindex="-1"></pre>
        
    </div>
    <br>
```

Comment: This is kind of buggy: the caret starts to be incorrectly positioned after about five characters.

Comment: It works well for me, please attach a screenshot so i can see what is happening.

Comment: Ok i understand. Difference in browsers. This is how it looks in firefox: https://ibb.co/ns7zYD3. So this issue occurs in chromium browsers. I'll look into it :)